# Activity not whitelisted

Tags: java, android, google-play

I recently launched an application on google play. it was working fine on my debug build, but it started crashing when i downloaded the released version from google play. I now try installing the `app-release.apk` (Although i uploaded the `app.abb` bundle, but i don't know how to get an apk out of it) generated via android studio and it gives me the following logs:

```
2019-08-27 05:46:09.978 819-852/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2019-08-27 05:46:09.982 1449-8273/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: Iop tryGetService failed
2019-08-27 05:46:09.998 1449-8273/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedin.curioustools.water_reminder/in.curioustools.water_reminder.ui.StartActivity/1
2019-08-27 05:46:09.998 1449-8273/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedin.curioustools.water_reminder/in.curioustools.water_reminder.ui.StartActivity/1
2019-08-27 05:46:10.008 1449-10327/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedin.curioustools.water_reminder/in.curioustools.water_reminder.ui.StartActivity/1
2019-08-27 05:46:10.041 23961-23961/? E/.water_reminde: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
...
```

full logs are [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vyRM6pkKTJ/) .What am i doing wrong?  why my activity is not whitelisted? Here is my activity and manifest:

```xml
//manifest

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="in.curioustools.water_reminder">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.screen_dashboard.DashBoardActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.screen_intro.IntroInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />
        <activity android:name=".ui.StartActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".broadcast_recievers.NotificationActionReceiver" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and:

```java
//StartActivitty.java
package in.curioustools.water_reminder.ui;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.SharedPreferences;
        import android.os.Bundle;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

        import in.curioustools.water_reminder.R;
        import in.curioustools.water_reminder.services.ServicesHandler;
        import in.curioustools.water_reminder.ui.screen_intro.IntroInfoActivity;
        import in.curioustools.water_reminder.ui.screen_dashboard.DashBoardActivity;

        import static in.curioustools.water_reminder.db.pref.PrefUserDetails.*;

public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //private static final String TAG = "startActivity";
    Class classToBeLaunched;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        ServicesHandler.updateServices(this);

        SharedPreferences pref= getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean shownOneTime=pref.getBoolean(KEYS.KEY_SHOWN_INFO_ACTIVITY, Defaults.HAS_SHOWN_INTRO_INFO_ACTIVITY);
        classToBeLaunched = shownOneTime ?DashBoardActivity.class:IntroInfoActivity.class;
        startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, classToBeLaunched));
        finish();

    }

}
```

Comment: I do not recognize that message. Note, though, that your crash is something else: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class d.a.a.b.a.q]`. You would need to decode that class reference using your ProGuard mapping file. It appears that a constructor perhaps was removed by ProGuard, and you need that constructor to be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled code minifying in the gradle and the issue was solved

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: :D And how did you do that?

Comment: @ofundefined i updated my answer to show how i did it

Comment: What is the reason for this issue ? In my case, minifyEnabled is false, but still i'm facing the same problem.

Comment: I don't recommend this. If you use minifyEnabled false in a release build, you basically make your app open source. It wont minify your code in the build that you will publish on Google Play.

Comment: In My Case I got error in minifyEnabled False, And SuccessFully Working in minifyEnabled True :D

Comment: @menno Exposing the code of a software piece does _not_ somehow magically make it "open source".

Comment: @arkascha but it becomes no effort for someone to unzip your .apk and decompile the bytecode to java with any freely available java decompiler. And if not obfuscated, the decompiled code is very well readable.

Comment: @menno That is correct. But there is a difference between "open source" and you being able to read the source code. "open source" refers to a license model.

Answer (score 2):

minifyEnabled=false is by default on all new projects you create with Android Studio for debug and release configurations. Even in this case you may see the following errors in Logcat:

> E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListe**
>   E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListe**

In my cases they are preceeded by android debug message

> The activity in ApplicationInfo {********} is now in focus and seems to be in full-screen mode.

The last is not correct because the tested application do not request full-screen mode.